# Scripts em paralelo usando Threading - Python

Tags: python, funções, multithreading

Eu estou tentando executar scripts em paralelo no Python, utilizando a biblioteca threading, mas não estou conseguindo aplicar para o meu caso. Acredito que o problema seja ao receber a minha função, porém, mesmo criando uma lista, ele retorna o erro. Estou tendo problema ao executar a função.

```
import threading
import os

def inicia_programa(args): 
  for nome_arquivo in args: 
     os.system('py -3.8 {}'.format(nome_arquivo))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    arquivos = ['Script1','Script2','Script3']

    processos = []
    for arquivo in arquivos:
        processos.append(threading.Thread(target=inicia_programa, args=('Script1','Script2','Script3)))

    for processo in processos:
        processo.start()
```

o erro apresentado indica isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa de threads para isso. Use o módulo `subprocess` e poderá iniciar múltiplos processos sem bloquear a thread principal.

Além disso, o módulo `subprocess` permite executar somente o python. Se você monitorar a sua lista de processos verá que o `os.system` roda dois processos, ele inicia uma shell para rodar o seu processo, desperdiçando assim tempo e recursos.

Outra dica é o uso da variável `sys.executable` - ela possui o caminho para o mesmo python que foi usado para rodar o script - assim você não precisará mudar seu programa quando for usar o python 3.9 ou qualquer outro.

```
import sys
import subprocess

arquivos = ['Script1.py','Script2.py','Script3.py']
processos = []

for arquivo in arquivos:
    processo = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, arquivo])
    processos.append(processo)

# neste ponto todos os scripts estão rodando em background ao mesmo tempo. 
# Vamos esperar todos eles terminarem:

for processo in processos:
    processo.wait()
```

Comment: Agora sim deu certo de uma maneira satisfatória. Obrigado